# Pie chart display just the first element in the series

Tags: php, highcharts

I want to display the number of projects per lab ,the list of lab is a collection

In my case the list of series are dynamic

My problem :The pie generate just the first project LAB

[image]

**ProjectLab Entity:**

```
class ProjectLab
{
 /**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Form", inversedBy="projectLab")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="form_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $form;
}
```

**Form entity:**

```
class Form
{

/**
 *.
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjectLab", mappedBy="form", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $projectLab;
}
```

**my chartPie function:**

```
public function chartPie(Survey $survey)
{

    $center = $survey ->getCenter();
    $form = $survey->getForm();
    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('containerpie');
    $ob->chart->type('pie');
    $ob->chart->options3d(array('enabled' => true,'alpha'=> '45','beta'=> null));


    $ob->plotOptions->pie(array(
        'depth' => '25',
        'allowPointSelect'  => true,
        'cursor'    => 'pointer',
        'dataLabels'    => array('enabled' => true , 'format'=> '{point.name}'),
        'showInLegend'  => true
    ));

    $ob->title->text('List project per lab');

   $listLabProject =$form ->getProjLab();


    foreach($listLabProject as $lab) {

        $data = array(
            array($lab->getProjLab(),$lab->getNbProject()));
    }

    $ob->series(array(array('type' => 'pie','name' => 'Number', 'data' =>    $data)));
    return $ob;
}
```

Comment: How does the $data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `foreach` loop, you're overwriting `$data` each time instead of appending to it.  Try something like this:

```
$data = array();
foreach($listLabProject as $lab) {
    array_push($data,array($lab->getProjLab(),$lab->getNbProject()));
}
```